# GXT field value update onblur

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, onblur

Let's talk about the GXT v3 Fields.

There are two frames A & B.

Frame A has a set of fields and a submit button SA. Submit button reads the Fields in Frame A.
Frame B has only a submit button SB, which reads the Fields in Frame A.

Perform the following steps.

1. Enter data into a field F1 in Frame A.
2. Click on an region in Frame A or click on submit button of Frame A.
3. Debug on F1 getCell() will show that it has a value.

Perform the following alternate steps.

1. Enter data into a field F1 in Frame A.
2. Click on button in Frame B.
3. Debug on F1 getCell() will show that it does not have a value.

This is problematic for me. Therefore, I wish to know the difference in the onblur actions of the fields in Frame A between clicking on button SA and button SB.

What actions does onblur of Field F1 performs when clicking on Frame A that the onblur of Field F1 does not perform when clicking on Frame B?

If I know that difference, then I would be able to execute that difference.

Comment: When you say 'Frame', do you mean the GWT widget Frame (i.e. an iframe)? If so, you may be experiencing the browser's own cross-frame focus issues - might be worth verifying that a regular DOM change or blur event would be fired by focusing on something in another frame. GXT fields (at least the `<input>` based ones) key off of those events to flush out the value from the user - if the browser hasn't yet told the JS, it can't tell you. One last thought: some fields support `getCurrentValue()` to directly read and parse data from the dom - might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple.

Simply choose any two fields in frame A.

```
public void focusA(){
  frameA.getField1().focus();
  frameA.getField2().focus();
  frameA.focus();
}
```

The button click handler in Frame B should call focusA() before flushing the field values.

What focusA() does is

- focus on any other field would trigger update from DOM to Field Editor value, except the field being focused.
- in which case, trigger another random field to trigger update of first field.
- then prevent focus from sticking to the last field being focused (to prevent inadvertent field editing by user) by focusing on the container.